# Using internet for ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, internet-security

There is an option to connect to the internet while installing ubuntu. is it not dangerous to use public wifi for that purpose? Is it secure to do so?

Comment: I don't use public access points which are not encrypted.  You will have to decide if thats something you want to do.

Comment: but would it be any security problem with not having a firewall while installing it?

Comment: If your running any operating system without a firewall and security software your asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Debian and Ubuntu cryptographically sign all packages, so yes, it is secure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt